# GetDlgCtrlID and GetLastError returning 0

Tags: c++, winapi, error-handling, desktop

I'm doing a WIN32 application and I need to keep track (or get in someway) the ID of the different statics elements to change the colors.

**The problem comes because the function GetDlgCtrlID is returning 0 and GetLastError  is returning also a non error value.**

This is the class where I'm trying to get the ID and save it.

```
Casilla::Casilla(HWND* window, std::set<int>* stackToEnable, std::set<int>* stackToDisable)
{
    m_window = window;
    m_wID = GetDlgCtrlID(*window);
    std::string str = GetLastErrorAsString();
    m_setToEnable = stackToEnable;
    m_setToDisable = stackToDisable;
}

DWORD WINAPI Casilla::Enable()
{
    InvalidateRect(*m_window, NULL, TRUE);
    m_setToEnable->insert(m_wID);
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI Casilla::Disable()
{
    InvalidateRect(*m_window, NULL, TRUE);
    m_setToDisable->insert(m_wID);
    return 0;
}

//Returns the last Win32 error, in string format. Returns an empty string if there is no error.
std::string Casilla::GetLastErrorAsString()
{
    //Get the error message, if any.
    DWORD errorMessageID = ::GetLastError();
    if (errorMessageID == 0)
        return std::string(); //No error message has been recorded

    LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;
    size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, errorMessageID, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);

    std::string message(messageBuffer, size);

    //Free the buffer.
    LocalFree(messageBuffer);

    return message;
}
```

And this is the code that create the element and the "Casilla" to keep track of the ID.

```
void AddSlot(HWND hWnd)
{   
    HWND tmp = CreateWindowW(L"static", L"TO CHANGE COLOR", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER, 500, 500, 100, 100, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    Casilla* cas = new Casilla(&tmp, windowsToChangeColorToEnable, windowsToChangeColorToDisable);
}
```

Comment: When you create the control you aren’t giving it an ID.

Comment: The ID is zero because you don't specify it. You are also holding a pointer to a local variable that no longer exists.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so true. I came from C# and still strugling with stack/heap objects.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Where should I give the ID? I checked the documentation for CreateWindowW but I can't see where the ID is specified.

Comment: [CreateWindowW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindoww): *"`hMenu` (Type `HMENU`): A handle to a menu, **or specifies a child-window identifier** depending on the window style."* Since you are passing `WS_CHILD`, this argument receives the window ID.

Comment: `CreateWindow(...,(HMENU)ID,...)` should solve the problem with ID. You should also read up about "pass by reference" and passing pointers in C++. Normally you pass a valid `HWND` as a constant because you don't want to modify it (`void foo(const HWND window)`) The `new` operator should be avoided in C++ because it can cause memory leak. You can instead declare `Casilla cas;` as class member of global data.